# "data to be connected 'chisel3.core.UInt@103' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type" when rewrite OpenSoCFabric1.1.2 from Chisel2 to Chisel3

Tags: chisel

I am trying to rewrite OpenSoCFaric-1.1.2 from chisel2 to chisel3. But I encounter error messages "data to be connected 'chisel3.core.UInt@103' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type" for below code:

File: packettoFlit.scala  class: PacketToFlit
val flitWidth       = Flit.fromBits(0.U, parms).getWidth

File:channel.scala  object: Flit

```
object Flit {
    def head(h: HeadFlit) : Flit = {
        val f = new Flit(h.parms)
        f.x := f.union.pack("Head", h)
        f
    }

    def body(b: BodyFlit) : Flit = {
        val f = new Flit(b.parms)
        f.x := f.union.pack("Body", b)
        f
    }

    def fromBits(n: UInt, parms: Parameters) : Flit = {
        val f = new Flit(parms)
        f.x := n
        f
    }

    /*
    def zeroHead(parms: Parameters) : HeadFlit = {
        val x = new HeadFlit(parms)
        x.
    }
    */
}
```

And now I don't have good ideas about how to rewrite such code segments to fix the error. Could you give some help or suggestions ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see more of the error message (line number) and more of the code to provide a definitive answer, but our guess is that somewhere a UInt(x.W) is being used where a literal (y.U) is expected, or a Wire()/WireInit() wrapper is missing.

NOTE: LBL is actively migrating this code to Chisel3. You might be better off waiting for their work to be published.

Comment: [error] (run-main-2) chisel3.core.Binding$ExpectedHardwareException: data to be connected 'chisel3.core.UInt@103' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type
chisel3.core.Binding$ExpectedHardwareException: data to be connected 'chisel3.core.UInt@103' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type
        at chisel3.core.requireIsHardware$.apply(Binding.scala:31)
        at chisel3.core.Data.connect(Data.scala:291)
        at chisel3.core.Data.$colon$eq(Data.scala:363)
        at OpenSoC.Flit$.fromBits(channel.scala:100)
        at OpenSoC.PacketToFlit.<init>(packetToFlit.scala:98)

Comment: (line 98) PacketToFlit val flitWidth = Flit.fromBits(0.U, parms).getWidth

Comment: def fromBits(n: UInt, parms: Parameters) : Flit = {
        val f = new Flit(parms)
        f.x := n    (line 100, file channel.scala)
        f
    }

Comment: Jim, thanks your response firstly. I figure out the key source code in commnets.

Comment: Can you post the source code for `class Flit`? It looks to me like the issue is inside the construction of the Flit in `val f = new Flit(parms)`

Comment: Thank you for sharing the rest of the code. As indicated in the original answer, you need to wrap Chisel types in `Wire` when you expect them to be part of the hardware graph. Because class `Flit` extends `Bundle`, it is a Chisel data type, and if you want an instance of it to be part of the circuit you should wrap it in Wire, ie. `val f = new Flit(b.parms)` should be `val f = Wire(new Flit(b.parms))`

Answer (score 0):

Below is source code for class Flit.

```
class Flit(parms: Parameters) extends Bundle {
    val union   = new BitUnion(Map("Head" -> new HeadFlit(parms), "Body" -> new BodyFlit(parms)))
    val x       = UInt(union.width.W)
    val numVCs  = parms.get[Int]("numVCs")

    def asHead(dummy: Int = 0) : HeadFlit = union.unpack[HeadFlit]("Head", x)
    def asBody(dummy: Int = 0) : BodyFlit = union.unpack[BodyFlit]("Body", x)

    def whenHead(block: HeadFlit => Unit) { union.whenTag[HeadFlit]("Head", x)(block) }
    def whenBody(block: BodyFlit => Unit) { union.whenTag[BodyFlit]("Body", x)(block) }

    def isHead(dummy: Int = 0) : Bool = union.tagEquals("Head", x)
    def isBody(dummy: Int = 0) : Bool = union.tagEquals("Body", x)
    def isTail(dummy: Int = 0) : Bool = {
        val tailBit = Bool()
        when (isHead()) {
            tailBit := union.unpack[HeadFlit]("Head", x).isTail
        } .otherwise {
            tailBit := union.unpack[BodyFlit]("Body", x).isTail
        }
        tailBit
    }
    def getVCPort(dummy: Int = 0) : UInt = {
        val vcBits = UInt(log2Ceil(numVCs).W)
        when (isHead()) {
            vcBits := union.unpack[HeadFlit]("Head", x).vcPort
        } .otherwise {
            vcBits := union.unpack[BodyFlit]("Body", x).vcPort
        }
        vcBits
    }

    //override def clone = { new Flit(parms).asInstanceOf[this.type] }
    override def cloneType: this.type = new Flit(parms).asInstanceOf[this.type]
    // override def width : Int = {x.width}
}
```

Thanks a lot!
Bibo